# App service name is empty on Azure -> Pipelines -> Releases

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I created a pipeline which works correct. Now I want to create a release, but when I add a task, dropdown list "App service name" is empty.

[image]

If I type "App service name" manually I get en error under releasing:

```
2020-04-27T14:51:14.0990839Z 
##[error]Error: Resource 'Blin...' doesn't exist. Resource should exist before deployment.
```

Can anybody explain it? Thanks!

Comment: Does the service principal have appropriate access to the Azure subscription?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your subscription do not have the permission to view that app service, refer to these steps below to check it:

1. Go to portal.azure.com
2. Switch to the tenant that your subscription linked to
3. Click Resource groups service
4. Check the Subscription value of the resource group that contains your app service

Comment: Thank you a lot! I was missing resource and web app. :)

Comment: I have checked everything as you mentioned but still dropdown listing "No Result Found"